# why does firebase simulator throw a invalid agument error when i test for update or create?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**This is my error:**
Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [10], column [13]. Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]

**When i run this i have used all the resources i can find on the web and found nothing that will work (the allow read works and create does when i just use isSignedIn() ) ... little help please.**

```html
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents{
    match /users/{documents} {     
  function isSignedIn() {
         return request.auth != null;
    }
  function getRole(admin){
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users.[request.auth.uid]).data.admin;     
   }        
     allow read: if true; 
     allow write: if getRole(admin) == true;    
    }
  }  
}
```

[**Here is my db**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKnWg.png)

Comment: I face similar issues quite frequently.  Usually, it's something simple, and then I have to not touch my Firestore rules for fear of breaking them again...  Might it have to do with trying to `get()` a document that doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that user authentificated before trying to get role of user in getRole function. Exception occurs because request.auth.uid is null.
Also check that users.[request.auth.uid] is valid path.